# Model composition where instance of class is used multiple times

Tags: class-diagram, emf, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I want to model the following scenario:

- A message a consists of one or more base types.
- Base types are uint8 .. uint64 and int8 .. int64.
- A message can also contain other messages.

---

**Example:**

Message position

- uint8 x
- uint8 y

Message movement

- position start
- position end
- uint8    speed

---

This is what i modeled in Sirius so far
[image: Sirius model]

The issue here is that I cannot link the message position twice to the message movement. Can you please provide a approach of modelling this problem?

Comment: What is the "message movement"?

Comment: In the example I provided there are two messages, one called position and one called movement where the message position only consists of base types and the message movement consists of two other messages which are both positions as well as one base type.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any of those in your diagram.

Comment: Is it that you can instantiate only the way shown in the text above? If so, why don't you have two different classes?

Comment: How would a solution with two different classes look like?

Comment: Well, just create two classes  `MessagePosition` and `MessageMovement` that represent the specifics you explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modelization is lacking one "layer" to represent your "message type" / "message instance" structure.

I think what you need to do is something a bit like this:

- Class `MessageType` with a containment towards `BaseType` (which IMO should be renamed something like `MessageDataType`)
- Class `MessageInstance` with a containment towards itself and a reference to a `MessageType`.

Then you end user must first create a `MessageType` instance, called "position" and a second one called "movement". Then create three `MessageInstance` instances, two pointing towards `MessageType` "movement" and one containing the first two `MessageInstance` instances.

I would also advise seriously thinking about how you want to name your concepts, because there is a potential confusion between an Ecore instance of one of your EClass and the fact that you are effectively modeling a type/instance structure.